# Create buttons using jquery-mobile that stretch fullscreen

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, height

I'm trying to create a home page screen where the buttons in the body take up the full screen after the header and footer.  Ideally the buttons 2x2 will stretch out to the remaining space on the screen.

I tried using ui-grid-a to stretch the buttons to the width of the screen but was unable to alter the height to the screensize.

```
   <section id="Home" data-role="page">
   <header data-role="header">
        <a href="#Home">Home</a>
        <h1>testapp</h1>
        <a href="#Setup">Setup</a>
   </header>

   <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#button1" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button1</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#button2" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button2</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#button3" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button3</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#button4" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button4</a></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

   <footer data-role="footer"  data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"style="text-align:left"><a href="#button1"  data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="false">button1</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"style="text-align:right"><a href="#button2" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="false">button2</a></div>
        </fieldset>
   </footer>
```

I'm a noobie at coding so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: remove this tag: <div data-role="content"> it adds space

Comment: When I do that, my buttons are in 1 column.  but thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what your looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/JAjJp/1/embedded/result/

#### CSS

```
<style>
   .button{padding:25% 0;}
</style>
```

#### HTML

```
<section id="Home" data-role="page">
   <header data-role="header">
        <a href="#Home">Home</a>
        <h1>testapp</h1>
        <a href="#Setup">Setup</a>
   </header>

   <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#button1" class="button" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button1</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#button2" class="button" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button2</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#button3" class="button" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button3</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#button4" class="button" data-role="button" data-inline="false">button4</a></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

   <footer data-role="footer"  data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"style="text-align:left"><a href="#button1"  data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="false">button1</a></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"style="text-align:right"><a href="#button2" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-inline="false">button2</a></div>
        </fieldset>
   </footer>
</section>​
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out what css i needed to overwrite jquerymobile

Comment: I noticed the button doesn't display the (heightwise) to the rest of screen. But this is definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: Just play with it a bit. But that is the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Pq9YP/

Using a navbar with one list item